# How to debug IML functions in custom Integromat apps?

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I know that it is possible to write tests for IML functions using the VS Code plugin but couldn't find anything similar to `console.log`. Is logging available in IML functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `debug()` function inside your own IML functions instead of trying to use `console.log`. When your IML function is called from any module, the output from the `debug()` function will be shown in the Live Stream panel within Chrome's [Integromat DevTool](https://support.integromat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015349160-Integromat-DevTool) extension. Similar output will also be available in the Console tab unless this feature is turned off in the DevTool.

For example, writing `debug("This is a debug message.");` in your IML function will produce the following output:
[image: output from the debug() function]

Integromat DevTool can be downloaded from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/integromat-devtool/ainnemkhpnjgkhcdkfbhmlenkhehmfhi).